# Why is [object Object] to lowser case and capitalized?

Tags: javascript, dom, logging, javascript-objects

I was wondering why `[object Object]`'s first parameter is lower case and the second one is capitalized? Is it because the first paramter represents the `Object.property` and the second one the `Object.propety = "Value"`?

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-object.prototype.tostring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

string representations of Types in JavaScript are lowercase:

```
  typeof {} // "object"
```

Therefore it makes sense that it starts with `[object ...]`.

The second part (`Object`) represents the name of the constructor function the object was created with, and by convention constructors have capitalized names (e.g. `[object Math]`, `[object Null]` ...).